# Something wrong with my javascript move effect

Tags: javascript

This is the code http://jsbin.com/opevow/64/edit

You can edit it and press top left corner to test.

Only the "down" function works.

The "left" is moving to left side but then moving to top..

Other doesn't work at all...(keep slibing in place...). I was nearly collapsed..

I think click 4 boxes at the same time will cause strange problem,so you can edit this code and test a single box.

Thank you cordially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you forget to break your switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

in your markup you have:

```
<div id="box1" onclick=move(100,300,"box1",1)>right</div>
```

HTML attribute values **should** always be quoted. The quotes can be omitted if they contain only members of a limited set of characters, but for safety you should always quote them.

That won't completely fix your problem, but it's a start.